# Add play button, h1, P on video

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

[image]

**How can I design this in HTML/CSS,**

- video is as full div background in blurred way.
- Play button - will play the video.
- h1 tag p tag on top of video

Please put me in a right direction, Thanks

Comment: Please provide a  Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Don't provide external links to any images or videos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.play').click(function () {
        if($(this).parent().prev().get(0).paused){
            $(this).parent().prev().get(0).play();
            $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('blurEffect');
            $('.content').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.video').on('ended',function(){
        $(this).addClass('blurEffect');
      $('.content').show();
    });
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.blurEffect {
    -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
    -o-filter: blur(7px);
    -moz-filter: blur(7px);
    -ms-filter: blur(7px);
    filter: blur(7px);
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}

.play {
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 25px;
}

.play:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <video class="video blurEffect"> 
        <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
        <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
        <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
        <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
    </video>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="play">►</div>
            <h1>Watch the movie</h1>
            <p>Other text. Other text. Other text. Other text. </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with your answer

Comment: thanks @eshan, it worked great. But only thing missing is , video is not displaying as a blurred background and not adjusting the width as per full screen.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can use CSS property:`position` ,`left` and `top` to change location of html elements.

**2.** `HTMLMediaElement` has a method named `play()`,you can call `play()` in javascript to make `<video>` to start playing video. About HTMLMediaElement,look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement).

**3.** You can use `z-index` CSS property to make sure that `<button>`,`<h>` and `<p>` is on top of . About z-index,look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Answer (score -1):

I have created a simple Codepen document that will point you in the right direction. It's using HTML and CSS elements only, with minimal code.

It's also using a CSS filter called blur to blur the background image and using scale to increase the size of the image to ignore the white borders the blur filter applies.

[LINK TO CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/QqxGyb)

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper"></div>

<div class="center">
  <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h1>Watch the others</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit enean semper mattis elementum/</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff
}

.center i {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```